# UIScrollView does not scroll + second scrollView shows nothing

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

it is unpleasant for me but I need some help with my UIScrollViews. They are both arranged subviews of a stackView on my MainVC.
The weird thing is that only one of them is showing content, although I used the same code for both scrollViews. The second problem is that they do not scroll, here is my code:

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    var views = [UIImageView]()
    
    //StackView
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let topView = UIScrollView()
    let bottomView = UIScrollView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = MyColors.soft_pink
        
        prepare_data()
        print(views.count)
        
        
    }
    
    //MARK: - GUI
    
    func setUpStackView() {
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
        stackView.spacing = 5
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(topView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(bottomView)
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
        
        setUpTopView()
        setUpBottomView()
       
    }
    
    func setUpTopView() {
        topView.delegate = self
        topView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        topView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        topView.layer.borderWidth = 10
        topView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        topView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        topView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        topView.isPagingEnabled = true
        
        topView.contentSize = CGSize(width: topView.frame.width * CGFloat(views.count),height: topView.frame.height)
        
        for i in 0..<views.count {
            topView.addSubview(views[i])
            views[i].frame = CGRect(x: topView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: 350, height: 250)
            views[i].layer.cornerRadius = 25
        }
        
        topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    
    }
    
    func setUpBottomView() {
        bottomView.delegate = self
        bottomView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        bottomView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        bottomView.layer.borderWidth = 10
        bottomView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        bottomView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        bottomView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        bottomView.isPagingEnabled = true
        
        bottomView.contentSize = CGSize(width: bottomView.frame.width * CGFloat(views.count),height: bottomView.frame.height)
        
        for i in 0..<views.count {
            bottomView.addSubview(views[i])
            views[i].frame = CGRect(x: bottomView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: 350, height: 250)
            views[i].layer.cornerRadius = 25
        }
        
        bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    }
    
    func prepare_data() {
        for x in 1...6 {
            let woman = UIImage(named: "woman\(x)")
            let womanView = UIImageView(image: woman)
            womanView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            views.append(womanView)
        }
        setUpStackView()
    }
    
   

}
```

Could someone please be so kind and tell me what I have wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug by printing values. `bottomView.frame.width` was zero at initialisation, so update subviews in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. There are more ways you can look for frame update detection.

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateSubviewFrames()
        }
    }

    func updateSubviewFrames() {
        print(bottomView.frame)
        bottomView.contentSize = CGSize(width: bottomView.frame.width * CGFloat(views.count),height: bottomView.frame.height)
        for i in 0..<views.count {
            views[i].frame = CGRect(x: bottomView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: 350, height: 250)
            views[i].layer.cornerRadius = 25
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done a few things wrong...

First, because it's easy -- the reason you don't see anything in your Top scroll view is because you add your image views (from the `views` array) to `topView`, and then you add them to `bottomView` ***which removes them from `topView`***!

So, you need one array of views for `topView` and an array of **other** views for `bottomView`.

Next, you are using auto-layout / constraints to size and position your stack view, then trying to use the frames of the stack view's arranged subviews -- for example:

```
bottomView.contentSize = CGSize(width: bottomView.frame.width * CGFloat(views.count),height: bottomView.frame.height)
```

but, that's all being done in functions called from `viewDidLoad()` when auto-layout has not yet configured the view frames.

You're also adding your scroll view's as arranged subviews of the stack view, but then constraining them to the stack view (which is not the way to do it):

```
topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

As a side note: the easiest way to manage a paged scroll view is to embed the "pages" (your image views) in a horizontal stack view, setting the width of each view to the width of the scroll view's Frame Layout Guide (minus desired spacing).

Here's a modified version of your code to take a look at:

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    var topViews = [UIImageView]()
    var botViews = [UIImageView]()

    //StackView
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let topView = UIScrollView()
    let bottomView = UIScrollView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPink // MyColors.soft_pink
        
        prepare_data()
        setUpStackView()
        setUpTopAndBottomViews()
    }
    
    func prepare_data() {
        // create 6 image views
        //  for BOTH Top and Bottom scroll views

        // I'll assume you have "woman" and "man" images
        for x in 1...6 {
            let woman = UIImage(named: "woman\(x)")
            let man = UIImage(named: "man\(x)")

            let womanView = UIImageView(image: woman)
            womanView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            topViews.append(womanView)

            let manView = UIImageView(image: man)
            manView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            botViews.append(manView)
        }
    }
        
    func setUpStackView() {
        // setup stack view
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        // .alignment should be .fill, not .center
        //stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        // let's use .fillEqually instead of .equalCentering
        //stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 5
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(topView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(bottomView)
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
    }
    
    func setUpTopAndBottomViews() {
        // setup both scroll views with the same properties
        [topView, bottomView].forEach { v in
            v.delegate = self
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 25
            v.layer.masksToBounds = true
            v.layer.borderWidth = 10
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            v.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            v.isPagingEnabled = true
        }
        
        // let's use auto-layout here
        //  if you want horizontal paged scrolling, easiest route is to
        //  use a horizontal stack view
        
        // create a stack view
        let topStack = UIStackView()
        topStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topStack.spacing = 10
        
        // add stack view to topView
        topView.addSubview(topStack)
        
        for i in 0..<topViews.count {
            topStack.addArrangedSubview(topViews[i])
            topViews[i].layer.cornerRadius = 25
            // set view width and height equal to
            //  topView's Frame Layout Guide
            //  allowing for 5-pts "padding" on the sides
            topViews[i].widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
            topViews[i].heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        // now we'll set constraints on the stack view to
        //  topView's Content Layout Guide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            topStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            topStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -5.0),
            topStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        // same thing with the bottom scroll view

        // create a new stack view
        let botStack = UIStackView()
        botStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        botStack.spacing = 10

        // add stack view to bottomView
        bottomView.addSubview(botStack)
        
        for i in 0..<botViews.count {
            botStack.addArrangedSubview(botViews[i])
            botViews[i].layer.cornerRadius = 25
            // set view width and height equal to
            //  bottomView's Frame Layout Guide
            //  allowing for 5-pts "padding" on the sides
            botViews[i].widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
            botViews[i].heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        
        // now we'll set constraints on the stack view to
        //  bottomView's Content Layout Guide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            botStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            botStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            botStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -5.0),
            botStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```